Powershell 7.4.2 - Get-ADGroupMember | Get-ADUser not working
I am using Powershell 7.4.2. When attempting to run a script like below I got the following the error message.
But , This script works in Powershell 5.1.
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'APPS Users' | Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname,enabled,memberof

My error message:
Get-ADUser: The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

UPDATE :
$Groups = "apps users","apps External Users"
$groupMemberships = foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    $adGroup = Get-ADGroup -Identity $group
    if ($adGroup) {
         $groups2 = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $adGroup.SamAccountName
           foreach ($group2 in $groups2) {
                Get-ADUser -Identity $group2.SamAccountName -Properties samaccountname,enabled,memberof
                }
    } 
    else {
        Write-Warning "Group '$group' could not be found.."
    }
}


Run first part by itself and see what it returns : Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'APPS Users'



Your symptoms imply that, in your PowerShell (Core) 7 sessions only, you're using implicit remoting, possibly in the context of using a locally installed ActiveDirectory module via the Windows PowerShell Compatibility functionality or the - now obsolete - external WindowsCompatibility module module that preceded it.

With a locally installed ActiveDirectory module, you do not need this approach, as you can use the ActiveDirectory directly in PowerShell 7, which will make your problem go away.

With implicit remoting you indeed can not directly pipe Get-ADGroupMember output to Get-ADUser, because the invariably involved serialization results in loss of type fidelity, causing Get-ADUser not to recognize the pipeline input (as implied by you later stating that what your Get-ADUser call outputs in PowerShell 7 are objects of type [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] rather than the usual ADUser instances.

You may situationally still have a need to use implicit remoting (in either PowerShell edition), namely if you're using implicitly remoting proxy cmdlets (created with Export-PSSession) that relay calls to an ActiveDirectory module on a remote machine. In that case, the best workaround is to use a delay-bind script-block argument that passes an identifying property value such as .SamAccountName to Get-ADUser's -Identity parameter.
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'APPS Users' | 
  Where-Object ObjectClass -eq user |
  Get-ADUser -Identity { $_.SamAccountName } -Properties samaccountname, enabled, memberof




Note that - whether or not the above workarounds is needed - the  Where-Object ObjectClass -eq user filterThanks, Theo. is required for robust operation, given that Get-ADGroupMember may situationally not only emit user instances (ADUser), but also computer instances and nested groups (the base class from which all of these types derive is ADPrincipal, the documented output type); the latter two output types are by definition not suitable as pipeline input to Get-ADUser.
Thus, the robust formulation of your original command is:
# Works only if no implicit remoting is involved.
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity 'APPS Users' | 
  Where-Object ObjectClass -eq user |
  Get-ADUser -Properties samaccountname,enabled,memberof





Nice. Saw this on the SO home page looking at other questions and it looked interesting. I haven't run into this yet personally, but I feel like I've probably made the same mistake in older code and will see this error eventually. Writing here to help me remember, and as a marker in case when it happens I find this via Google. It would be fun to see this, say, three years later and post a follow-up.
